# I am not able to add and remove the classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

My Code:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollWhere);
function scrollWhere(e) {
  var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var idScroll = $('.me').offset().top;
  var height = $("#half-who").height();
  if (windowScroll > idScroll) {
    $('.me').addClass('me-fixed');
  } else {
    $('.me').removeClass('me-fixed');
  }
}
```

I want to add a class when the scroll is past a certain point and remove it when is smaller than that certain point.

Comment: What value you get on `idScroll` ?

Comment: How many `div`'s with class `.me` do you have? Maybe there's the problem. You should use `id`'s instead.

Answer (score 1):

Get your `idScroll` value outside `scrollWhere` function as because it re-initiate calculation again and again and returns different values each time as because it has a `fixed` position. check below snippet for reference.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollWhere);
var idScroll = $('.me').offset().top;

function scrollWhere(e) {
  var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  //var height = $("#half-who").height();
  if (windowScroll > idScroll) {
    $('.me').addClass('me-fixed');
  } else {
    $('.me').removeClass('me-fixed');
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.me {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.me-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="me"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example to add a class when scroll passing a certain point. Hope you can get an idea. [>>> JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shalika247/3sL4kxq4/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 
  var winH = $(window).scrollTop();
 var ruler = $('.ruler').position().top;
  
  
  if(ruler < winH){
   $('.nav').addClass('me-fixed');
  }
  else{
   $('.nav').removeClass('me-fixed');
  }
  
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 1500px;
}
.nav{
  height: 50px;
  background: #a1bfbe;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav.me-fixed{
  background: #c2debf;
}
p{
  font-size: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.me-fixed p{
  display: block;
}

.ruler{
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <p>
    Fixed
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ruler">
</div>
```

Also if you can provide the html and css structure, it will be easy to identify the issue.

Comment: thank you so much!     what if I would like to remove the class when window.scroll is bigger then a value.
 window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollWhere);
     var idScroll = $('.me').offset().top;
function scrollWhere (e) {
        var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop() ;
     var height = $("#half-who").height();
if (windowScroll > idScroll) 
{
 $('.me').addClass('me-fixed');
 } 
else if(windowScroll < height )  {
 $('.me').removeClass('me-fixed');
}
else{
$('.me').removeClass('me-fixed');
}
}

Comment: Yes that looks fine. Also you can get rid of the `else if` part.